# JPA createNativeQuery not returning result list

Tags: jpa

I have a table which when I query as below I see 2 result rows

```
select avg(cast (ctc as DECIMAL(9,2))),
avg(cast(ectc as DECIMAL(9,2))),
experience from app.INFORMATION
where skills like '%Java%' group by experience
```

I converted the same to JPA as below

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> getSalaryAvg(String skill) {
    System.out.println("inside dao");
    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    Query q = em
            .createNativeQuery("select avg(cast (i.ctc as DECIMAL(9,2))),avg(cast(i.ectc as DECIMAL(9,2))),i.experience from INFORMATION i where i.skills like ?skill group by i.experience");
    q.setParameter("skill","%skill%");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> list = q.getResultList();

    for (Object[] result : list) {
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add(result[0].toString());
        l.add(result[1].toString());
        map.put(result[3].toString(), l);
        System.out.println(" results " + result[0].toString() + " "
                + result[1].toString());
    }

    return map;
}
```

But I don't see any results. Is there any syntax error in the native query?

Comment: errm, and the log says ?

Comment: And should there be results?  The first query is using '%Java%' while the other is using '%skill%'.

Comment: When I call this method public HashMap<String, List<String>> getSalaryAvg(String skill) I pass Java as the argument

Comment: There are no logs because the list is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris ! Found the error

```
Query q = em
        .createNativeQuery("select avg(cast (i.ctc as DECIMAL(9,2))),avg(cast(i.ectc as DECIMAL(9,2))),i.experience from INFORMATION i where i.skills like ?skill group by i.experience");
q.setParameter("skill","%"+skill+"%");
```

This solves the problem